# How to write null value to datetime array in PostgreSQL 8.3?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, quotes, sql-insert

I try to execute query:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
(
  timedate_array_field
)
VALUES
(
  '{NULL, NULL}'
)
```

But I get error "Could not convert string to DateTime: 'null'".

Comment: Do you want to insert a NULL (="non existing) array, or an array with two null values? Also 8.3 is no longer supported, you should really consider upgrading to 9.x as soon as possible

Comment: I want to insert array with two null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add single quotes for the value:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (timedate_array_field)
VALUES ('{NULL, NULL}')
```

[-> SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/07eea/2)

BTW, the data type is not called "DateTime" or "timedate" in Postgres, but [`timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped in original question. Edited question.

Comment: Thank you for your note about timestamp. It helps me to understand that problem was in my C++ code that executes query, not in SQL.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you prefer `'{NULL, NULL}'` over `ARRAY[NULL, NULL]`?

Comment: In my case `ARRAY[NULL, NULL]` doesn't work without explicit type declaration `::timestamp without time zone[]`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: As for me, either syntax variant is good. `'{...}'` is a bit shorter.